# what if i have some code wrapped with curly braces?

Tags: javascript

I don't get the answer for the question ,what will happen if i give like this? can anyone explain me please.Thanks in advance..

```js
{
  var x=10;
  var y=10;
  var sum;
  sum=x+y;
} 
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: nothing, in that case, nothing - different if you use `let` or `const` though - but that code .. nothing special or different happens

Comment: If you use `let` or `const`, maybe. but with `var`, no effect

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping code in curly braces creates a plain block. It's like a `for` loop which only runs once.

```
{
  // insert code here
}
```

is exactly equivalent to (assuming the variable `i` doesn't get used anywhere other than in the for loop declaration):

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  // insert code here
}
```

This can affect variable scoping if you're using `const` and `let`, which have block scope, rather than function scope.

```js
{
  // declared with const; is not visible outside of block
  const foo = 'foo';
}
console.log(foo);
```

With your code, though, all the variables are declared with `var`, so they have function (or, here, global) scope, so putting the code into a block has no effect - `x`, `y`, and `z` are global regardless.

Answer (score 0):

As you have wrapped your code in curly braces it acts as plain block. since you have used 'var' for x, y and sum variables there is no effect for scoping. but if you use 'let' for x, y and sum variables then it will give following console error.

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: sum is not defined"
```

In this case there is no effect x,y and sum acting as global.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of javascript. It happens because of **Hoisting**, anything declared with var it is hoisted at the top of the script file.

You should see this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting